# Nginx with let's encrypt in front of another nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have a development server with a list of docker container running. Every one of them have an application and an nginx in it, listening on port 80 with no ssl encryption, serving the application. So if I have 10 dockers, I would have 10 nginx (I know nginx is designed to serve multiple app, here is not the question).

I would like to have a single point of entry on the server, which would be an nginx, auto redirecting to http, with a certificate generated by let's encrypt.

Is this possible? Listening on port 443 with a let's encrypt, and redirecting to the port 80 of another nginx?
The goal here is to secure all the connections to my different dockers.

For you information, I was trying to use valian/docker-nginx-auto-ssl docker with the command

```
docker run -d   --name main-nginx \
    --restart on-failure \
    -p 80:80   -p 443:443 \
    -e ALLOWED_DOMAINS=www.scaniat.io,dev.scaniat.io,www.dev.scaniat.io,scaniat.io \
    -e SITES='scaniat.io=scaniat-frontend-master;dev.scaniat.io=scaniat-frontend-develop' \
    --network custom \
    valian/docker-nginx-auto-ssl
```

with no luck.

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: I have a warning alert in my browser, telling me the website is not secure. I have a certificate for the ssl, but it is the fallback one provided in the docker

Comment: This seems like an issue with the docker image not using the right certificate. Are there any logs from the container? Sorry for the late reply.